# Headphones with inline mic mute button hangs up the call Any way to mute instead?

Tags: iphone, headphones, ios

I just have a cheap pair of wired headphones with an inline mic with a mute button. I'm using an old iPhone 5 since I just broke my Nexus 6 screen. In Android, this button was a very quick way to mute and un-mute calls, crucial during conference calls. I just tried this for the first time on the iPhone and it hung up the call instead. Is there anyway to change this behavior to mute instead?

Comment: there is no way to mute the iphone's mic without pressing the right button on the call screen, not even with apple earphones

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to change this.  I really don't like that Apple has decided the single-click on the headphone switch will disconnect the call instead of muting the microphone.

You can do what I have and go [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) to provide iPhone feedback to Apple to make this change.

Comment: @Shanteva I've been leaving feedback about this since my iPhone 4 and they haven't changed it yet.  Hopefully, more people doing this will help convince them it's needed.  :-)